# wordpress, avada theme, white screen

Tags: php, wordpress

Got this error msg:

> A non well formed numeric value encountered in
>   /customers/f/c/4/helenagibson.se/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/class-avada-layout.php
>   on line 581

The 581 line says:

```
$site_width -= 2 * $page_padding;
```

Comment: can you echo `$page_padding` ?  I am thinking it's either a string or not set ...

Comment: And it might behoove you to put your expression in parens --  `$site_width -= (2 * $page_padding);`

Comment: which php version do you have? Try changing this string to $site_width -= 2 * (int) $page_padding;

Comment: Probably the error are on the avada config.